# How can I count from up from 0 to 100 in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

At the moment, I can make it count one by one every time I click as [my fiddle shows](http://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/Bwdfw/311/). Below is my html.

```js
var count = 0;

$("#update").click(function() {
  count++;
  $("#counter").html("My current count is: " + count + "%");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="update" type="button">Button</button>
<div id="counter">1</div>
```

How can I actually click on a button once only and make the county go from 0 to 100%?

Comment: `count < 100 && count++;` , I think you want to limit the count

Comment: Are you asking about an "animation sequence" that quickly runs from 0 to 100 after a single click?

Comment: @Thilo. Yes, I just rephrased the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*count from up from 0 to 100%*, You can use `setInterval` to update text with delay.

```js
$("#update").click(function() {
  var count = 0;
  var innterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (count == 100)
      clearInterval(innterval);
    count++;
    $("#counter").html("My current count is: " + count + "%");
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="update" type="button">Button</button>
<div id="counter">1</div>
```

Comment: It does exactly what I asked. Appreciate the support

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but if you want your count to go from 0 to 100 every time, then simply change

```
count++;
```

to

```
count+=100;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to make a loop from 0 to 100. please check below link for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/fatehjagdeo/Bwdfw/312/

or see code below:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<button id="update" type="button">Button</button>
<div id="counter"></div>

<script>
$("#update").click(function() {
for(var i=1;i<=100;i++){
    $("#counter").append("My current count is: "+i +"%<br>");
}


});
</script>
```